# Can't start Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have just configured dependencies for a simple Rails application using Gemfile, but I'm not able to start it anymore.

Here is the error message I get:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:274:in `activate': can't activate rails (= 2.3.5, runtime) for [], already activated rails-3.0.4 for [] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:216:in `try_activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    ...
```

The Gemfile is configured as follows

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rails', '3.0.4'
#gem 'rails', '2.3.5'
gem 'fastercsv', '1.5.4'
gem 'comma', '0.4.1'
```

and my environment.rb contains the following line

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '3.0.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Note that if I change that variable to 2.3.5, the server starts.

Any idea about what is causing the issue?

Comment: what happens if you remove the 3.0.4?

Comment: Then it works. However, the answer from chief is correct, the original app was not compatible with Rails 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change an existing gemfile run: bundle update.  Bundle install is only used for the initial setup.  And by the way we are at 3.0.5 now.  I am also wondering was this a rails 2 application?  Did you simply swap out the gem version number and expect it to then become a rails 3 app?  The environment.rb file in a rails 3 application does not show the rails gem version.

Comment: Thank you, you were absolutely right: the app was indeed based on an older version of Rails and then it was not compatible with 3.0.4/3.0.5